# Configure AFNetworking-RACExtensions with CocoaPods

Tags: afnetworking, cocoapods

I’ve been trying to **AFNetworking-RACExtensions** by using CocoaPods, but it always shows this error:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `ReactiveCocoa (= 2.1.8)` required by `Podfile`
- `ReactiveCocoa/no-arc` required by `ReactiveCocoa (2.1.8)`
- `ReactiveCocoa/Core` required by `ReactiveCocoa (2.1.8)`
- `ReactiveCocoa/no-arc` required by `ReactiveCocoa/Core (2.1.8)`
- `ReactiveCocoa (~> 2.1)` required by `ReactiveViewModel (0.1.1)`
- `ReactiveCocoa (~> 1.5.0)` required by `AFNetworking-RACExtensions (0.0.1)`
```

What can possible the the cause? Is it because AFNetworking-RACExtensions need AFNetworking 1.5 to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you need a version of `ReativeCocoa` that matches the semantic versioning required by `~> 1.5.0`. So I believe that would include the highest version matching `1.5.x` but not `1.6*`. Regardless `2.*` definitely isn't compatible with that. Since you're requiring `2.x` other places you can not have both of these versions at once. This is something CocoaPods can't handle because of the nature of duplicate symbols in Objective-C. The only way to fix this would be to downgrade your `2.x` version, although I assuming going down to before 2.0 would be difficult. Or the `AFNetworking-RACExtensions` upgrading to support ReactiveCocoa `2.x`.