# duplicate symbol in external framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

In my iOS XCode project I'm using an external, non open source library from a third party.
Now I want to add AFNetworking to my Project via cocoapods.
When I do so, I get multiple of errors like this one:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AFImageCache in:
    /Path/to/framework(UIImageView+AFNetworking.o)
    /Path/to/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods.a(UIImageView+AFNetworking.o)

63 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
```

It seams that the library is also using AFNetworking and by that is preventing me to use it. Is there any way to solve this (apart from not using the other framework, which is not an option)?

---

**Edit**

I managed to remove AFNetworking from the other framework by doing something similar to [this](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries). But now the framework doesn't find AFNetworking from cocoapods and I get `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`.

Is there a way to tell the framework where to find AFNetworking?

Comment: Post your Podfile here. Maybe even your Podfile.lock since it sounds like you're using non-public specs.

Comment: My podfile is basically just `pod 'AFNetworking'`. I don't load the other framework via cocoapods, so I actually don't think it has anything to do with cocoapods, or does it?.

Comment: Having a duplicate symbol for something usually means that you have multiple classes with the same name being loaded. If you think this is a bug in CocoaPods please submit a report [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods)

Comment: Yes, AFNetworking is loaded twice: once from me and once in the other framework. The question is, if I have any chance to use AFNetworking.

Comment: I managed to remove AFNetworking from the other framework by doing something similar to [this](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries). But now the framework doesn't find AFNetworking from cocoapods and I get `Undefined symbols for architecture i386`.
Is there a way to tell it where to find AFNetworking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot load the same library from two different places in the same project. This is a limitation of Objective-C, not CocoaPods. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299709/configure-afnetworking-racextensions-with-cocoapods/23300254#23300254) for more details.

Mainly to fix this you can only include AFNetworking in one place. Moving your other dependencies to CocoaPods could help you do this, assuming there are no conflicts in the versions as discussed in the linked answer.